# CefSharp.Wpf: FileLoadException when trying to load assembly

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

We have an old legacy application that is running with MS Access. We are in the process of migrating it to WPF. For that we created a `WinForms` control, that is showing our new WPF stuff in an `ElementHost`. This `WinForms` control is then somehow used in a COM ocx which then is placed on a MS Access form. This works so far, and for the time being this is like it is and I can't change it.

Until now we used the built-in `WebBrowser` control from .NET to show web sites, but since this control is based on IE 11, we are looking for a replacement. `WebView2` is not working in an `ElementHost`, so now we are investigating and testing `CefSharp` for WPF.

In all of my stand-alone tests it worked so far, but when I tried to integrate it into our software  today I stumbled upon a problem and I'm not sure how to fix that.

When I put the `ChromiumWebBrowser` control from `CefSharp` onto our WPF window and ran our software I got an `IO.FileLoadException` for the file `CefSharp.Wpf`. Checking that with `fuslogvw.exe` I've seen, that .NET looked for that file in the directory where the `MSAccess.exe` is situated, probably because this in fact **is** the executing assembly.

So I registered an `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to manually load the necessary files from where they are situated. This worked for

- CefSharp.Wpf
- CefSharp
- CefSharp.Core

But then it tried to load `CefSharp.Core.Runtime` and although this assembly is present I get an `IO.FileLoadException` (this file or one of its dependencies can't be found) when loading this assembly. I assume that it tries to find one of its own dependencies (non .NET) and looks for it in the wrong place (maybe the MS Access directory again?).

Do you have any suggestions how I can tell `CefSharp` and **all** of its dependencies (direct or indirect) where they can be found and where they should be loaded from?

Comment: Are you in the default appdomain? You can check via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.isdefaultappdomain?view=net-6.0 You cannot load CefSharp into a non default appdomain. It's a limitation of Visual C++. You'd need to run CefSharp out of process, which is actually what I'd recommend for plugins.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain` is true, when I check it in the place where I try to manually load the CefSharp libraries.

Comment: It looks like this problem only appears, when I debug the .NET code and use the Visdual Studio "Start" button for that. It doesn't seem to happen, when I attach to the MS Access process after the Cef* libraries have been loaded, and it doesn't seem to happen when I run the program without debugging.

Comment: Libcef.dll and associated resources should be loaded relative to CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll. You have a complex set of technologies in play that are likely the case of the strange behaviour. If you need to further troubleshoot this then I'd suggest using process monitor to see where the .Net runtime is attempting to load the files from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon You can manually load libcef.dll there's a helper class for that https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/102/CefSharp/CefLibraryHandle.cs#L39

Comment: Thank you for this information. Right now it seems to work (if I'm not debugging), so for now I'm going on with my tests.